# Listen to an event from node server js when new row is inserted to mysql table from app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to integrate **socket.io + node.js + mysql** . node-mysql is used to allow node.js to access the MySQL database. A table named tableA in the MySQL database updates with new data every 10 minutes.

Problem: Using node, I need the node server to continuously check tableA for changes whenever tableA gets updated(new row). **What is a good way to achieve this**?

I am thinking if I used **setInterval**(checkDb(tableA), 10*60*1000) for fetching all rows and check the changes, the checkDbquery function may not coincide with the database update.

I also happen to be using socket.io so will a good method be for the node system to emit('dbUpdated') from the node server to node client for realtime display of value.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing query to fetch all records and then check if anything has changed, you can create a trigger on your tableA. Whenever any operation occurs like insert in your case, just save a timestamp in some other field or other table. So whenever you query after certain intervals you should query this single filed and save this time stamp. And use it to compare it with next timestamp found in query to see if anything has changed.

Comment: So in every 10 min I have to check that table for getting timestamp right? also how to create trigger for tableA. Can you please help.

Comment: Lets create one more table as 'sync' and create 2 columns as 'table_name' & 'last_update' in it.

CREATE TABLE `sync` (
  `table_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Make a trigger after insert on tableA as below:

    BEGIN
        update sync set last_update = now() where table_name = 'tableA';
    END

And now query just sync table for last_update.